# MVC default page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here's the issue: When I press F5 to run the app, it tries to go to 
http://localport/Views/Home/Index.aspx 
and it gives a 404 error.

when I remove Views/Home/Index and
give it just http://localport/ -- it goes to the Index page.

I didn't change anything in the Routes in Global.ascx

What make it go to http://localport/Views/Home/Index.aspx

How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats just a "bug" in Visual Studio. You had that view selected when you hit F5 so it tries to navigate directly to that page.

Comment: Works perfectly for Webforms but not for MVC. Hence the quotes :)

Comment: Thankfully if you're using razor view engine the WebForms rule does not apply and you go to localport/.

Answer (score 5):

That is a Visual Studio behavior.  If you look at your Project Properties, under the Web tab, you can set a specific page to load when the app is run.  By default VS uses the page you're viewing - but in this case assumes it is a non-MVC web form.

Answer (score 2):

Press F5 when the current source file tab in focus is a .cs file (i.e. a Controller) instead of a .aspx file (i.e. a View).